# Facebook pixel event deduplication - Unique EventID

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to implement event deduplication:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/deduplicate-pixel-and-server-events#deduplication-best-practices

Should EventID be unique per user or globally?

Answer (score 3):

Event id should be unique per event instance. That's from a Facebook webinar I've attended. Same event ID received for many event instances will result in processing only the first event with that id that comes through. The rest will be discarded.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying what you mean by "event instance"?

Comment: hey @Christian, Facebook refers to `event instance` as a **single customer action**. In English, it's a page view, a purchase, add to cart etc, any standard or custom event that they measure. For example, if an user adds a product to cart (the event instance), that event is shared redundantly using a “browser + server connection”. So two instances of the same event via different channels but with the same id (that's when they deduplicate). If all your event event instances from all your users have the same id, only the first is is counted. Hope it helps, haven't touched this for a while :-).

Comment: @Christian if useful, here's the [recording of the webinar](https://www.facebook.com/business/webinars/how-to-use-conversion-api-developer-guide) I've attended. They also have a manual for developers - Conversions API Direct Integration Playbook for Developers - linked just above the Overview section on this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/guides/end-to-end-implementation/#overview).

Answer (score 1):

> If we find the same server key combination (event_id, event_name) and browser key combination (eventID, event) sent to the same pixel ID within 48 hours, we discard the subsequent events.

It can be concluded that a unique event_id should only be for events with the same event_name sent to the same pixel within 48 hours.

[Deduplication Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/deduplicate-pixel-and-server-events)